# npm run build-css npm ERR! Missing script: "build-css"

Tags: javascript, css, build, package.json

npm run build-css
npm ERR! Missing script: "build-css"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},

i have a package.json file and it has build but still writes an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.